# Computing stratum specific likelihood ratio in R

Tags: roc

I am looking for guidance on how to computer stratum specific likelihood ratios (SSLR) in R as my internet searches dont seem to be providing much info.
I have a sample of ~2500 participants who completed a questionnaire on psychological distress (total scores range 10-50) and also data which tells me if they are classified as having a depressive disorder (yes/no).

I computed ROC curves using the 'cutpointr' and 'PROC' packages and have determined an optimal cutoff value but i now need to compute SSLR's and cannot find any information on how to do actually execute this in R.
Beginner here - please limit the jargon in responses.
Thank you for the help in advance!